# How to disable or route the debug logs while using restTemplate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am trying to develop a CLI command which returns a list of employees from the server database using rest. I used restTemplate.getObject() method to get the list. This works fine, but in the console , I am getting debug logs like

```
3:06:58.564 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to     [application/xml, text/xml, application/*+xml, application/json]
13:06:58.989 [main] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "https://ip:8080/service/employee/list" resulted in 200 (OK)
```

I dont want these debug messages in my console. How to disable these ? Routing these messages to another log file can also be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using Logback. It is highly configurable, with possibility of log only a certain level of messages (only warnings or only errors) and the possibility to log to console (default, to a file, ...). You should read the [logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual) but here are some clues

Logback reads its configuration from a file `logback.xml` at the root of classpath

If you want to stop logging DEBUG messages (next level is info, then warn, error and off)

```
<configuration debug="true"> 

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <!-- encoders are  by default assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

If you want to log to a file :

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>testFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried both of these variants but it dint work. One more addition to my question is that I have some errors in my server logs related to logback .    2014-09-26 10:04:16,739 ERROR [Thread-2] STDERR (AbstractLoggingWriter.java:71) - SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
Does this have any relation with logs coming in console even after changing the logback.xml file?

Comment: I cannot know whether it is related, but you should make a decision about your logging system (slf4j + logback is an excellent choice but as any other choice it must be correctly configured) and fix this error before adjusting log level. BTW where did you put `logback.xml` ?

Comment: I have kept the logback.xml in src/main/resources Folder. I can see that the file testFile.log has been created but there are no content inside. The logs still come in the console.

Comment: @JavaWorld : then it means that you are mixing log systems. Fix the ` SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings` first, and make sure that you are only using slf4j and logback

Answer (score 1):

The java-based configuration instead of xml worked for me.

```
FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> myAppender = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
LoggerContext loggerContext=(LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.reset();

PatternLayoutEncoder layout=new PatternLayoutEncoder();
layout.setContext(loggerContext);
layout.setPattern("%X{first} %X{last} - %m%n");
layout.start();
myAppender.setAppend(true);
    myAppender.setFile("logs/testFile1.log");
    myAppender.setName("File1");
    myAppender.setEncoder(layout);
    myAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
    myAppender.start();
    ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logbackLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("Main");
    logbackLogger.addAppender(myAppender);
    logbackLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    logbackLogger.setAdditive(true);
```